# Converting Linq query to Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-sql

How can i convert the following linq to sql into lambda expression. Thanks.

```
 var existing = (from a in db.sms_imported_trn_code
                 where !db.sms_description.Any(m => m.trn_code == a.trn_code)
                 select new  { trn_code = a.trn_code }).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried the following query but its giving me an error. Please view image below.

[image: View Error Image]

My model classes are below

```
    public class sms_imported_trn_code
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string trn_code { get; set; }
        List<sms_imported_trn_code> sms_import_list { get; set; }
    }
}


 public class sms_description
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string trn_code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime create_date { get; set; }
        public string created_by { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: And what have you tried/researched before asking? This may help you: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/

Comment: Read [ask] and share your research towards the actual error. Without an error we can't do much.

Comment: now he has put an `error` for my solution.can you help me now ? :D @CodeCaster

Comment: On a side note, why are you using the reverse of Any (!db.sms_description.Any) rather than `All`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because you are writing "s.sms_description", sms_description is not part of class sms_imported_trn_code, its a separate class so you need to write db.sms_description

```
db.sms_imported_trn_code
  .Where(s => !db.sms_description.Any(m => m.trn_code == s.trn_code))
  .Select(t => new {trn_code = t.trn_code }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks it works. What other frameworks ORM you recommend other than entity framework?. Or it is still recommended by Microsoft.

Comment: I don't have much experience on any other framework, I prefer using entity framework.